# CSS Change the order of content between columns

Tags: html, css

Question goes beyond CSS and have therefore been closed.

---

I have several areas with content which I want in another order according to the viewport used.

On **large screens**, I want two columns and on **small screens**, I want one column - with the content in another order and vice versa.

I have tried to show in below image the layout. Written in a text is the layout on large viewports and the order of the boxes.

I would really like to keep the `flex-columns` if possible. I have tried with the setting the `order`-property without success.

I have updated below code so it clearly shows what I am trying to do.
Resizing below should be selfexplaining but I need things in two columns on larger viewports and things in another order on smaller viewports.

[See JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/SRIXH/sxq1a42p/32/)

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    align-content: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .flexcolumntop {
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .flexcolumnbottom {
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .red {
    background: red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .blue {
    background: blue;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .green {
    background: green;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .lime {
    background: lime;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .pink {
    background: pink;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .gray {
    background: gray;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    align-content: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .flexcolumntop {
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .flexcolumnbottom {
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .red p::before {
    content: "Order: 2";
  }
  .red {
    background: red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .blue p::before {
    content: "Order 5: ";
  }
  .blue {
    background: blue;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .green p::before {
    content: "Order: 1";
  }
  .green {
    background: green;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .lime p::before {
    content: "Order: 4";
  }
  .lime {
    background: lime;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .pink p::before {
    content: "Order: 6";
  }
  .pink {
    background: pink;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .gray p::before {
    content: "Order: 3";
  }
  .gray {
    background: gray;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flexcolumntop">
    <div class="red">
      <p>
        Red
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
      <p>
        Blue
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="pink">
      <p>
        Pink
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcolumnbottom">
    <div class="green">
      <p>
        Green
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="gray">
      <p>
        Gray
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="lime">
      <p>
        Lime
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to look into `@media` queries

Comment: This question is beyond `@media` queries. I need content to change columns when viewport change

Comment: Try using Grid.

Comment: It was my first thought but other solutions are welcome, so no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily solvable using `flexbox` and `order`, althrough you would have to get rid of grouping with flex-columns like you currently have (you can reorder only the columns inside the same parent, so it wouldn't be possible to do for ex. green -> red -> gray if they wouldn't have the same parent).

Cleaned up the css a bit and added `.morder` classes that just setup the order for mobile version. Also did minor html changes (each of the color elems now have a `.flexcol` parent and the items are ordered differently - but that could be avoided using `order` property on desktop as well if needed) :)

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.flexcol {
  flex: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}
.red, .blue, .green, .lime, .pink, .gray {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
.lime {
  background: lime;
}
.pink {
  background: pink;
}
.gray {
  background: gray;
}
  
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .flexcol {
    flex: 100%;
  }
  .morder-1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .morder-2 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .morder-3 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .morder-4 {
    order: 4;
  }
  .morder-5 {
    order: 5;
  }
  .morder-6{
    order: 6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flexcol morder-2">
    <div class="red">
      <p>
        Red
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcol morder-1">
    <div class="green">
      <p>
        Green
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcol morder-5">
    <div class="blue">
      <p>
        Blue
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcol morder-3">
    <div class="gray">
      <p>
        Gray
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcol morder-6">
    <div class="pink">
      <p>
        Pink
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcol morder-4">
    <div class="lime">
      <p>
        Lime
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On second thought my request seems to require more explanation. I have provided that in the code.

Comment: I like your thinking - making all the `div` into flexcolumns. Yet what if the boxes are not equally height? Some smaller and some way heigher?

Comment: I suppose it would be like "masonry".

Comment: I can think of one option (ordering `flex` elems into columns), but it would basically require you to set some height as a "breakpoint" for elements. Basically something like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZEMvN but it would still have a lot of drawbacks (you would probably have to use JS and the first column would always have to  be bigger).

Comment: Other than that, if you want masonry, why don't you use a masonry library? Or opt #2 just generate two versions of html? (one for desktop, the other for mobile).

Comment: I would rather keep this to one (responsive) version as this layout would be used on many pages. Also I would like not to use any externalsource CSS. I believe I might have to rethink things. I honest thought this would be easier. Hmm...

Comment: Well, you just walked into the "cannot be solved without doubling or js" zone. :) Anyways not sure why "used on many pages" means you cannot double it.

Comment: What a wonderfull zone :') I guess having an HTML-page for both mobile and desktop will require too much maintenance with content or I am not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: You don't need to copy entire page, you can just simply double the section you are interested in (i'm assuming you are already dynamically generating it in one way or another) and just conditionally show desktop or mobile version. :)

Comment: No I am not using any CMS or what so ever... And I guess my approach will be with jQuery. I have allready found some nice examples that I will study :)

Comment: Also I found this. Hope this might come in handy sometime. Masonry with CSS only.

http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Comment: @SimonJensen  Ah yes, thought about `column-count` before. Its similar to using `float` in that case really, but you are no longer able to controll the position of elements in the container and i thought its a requirement in your case.

Comment: I just realised that and I need that.

Answer (score 0):

With `Grid layout` you can define the template which define the way you sub element will be layout, when you specifie the `grid-template-areas` you define the way you sub elements will be position under the grid layout. And when It come to modifie the order of elements on certain viewport you will have just to change the `grid-template-areas` and on each subelement define the `grid-area` to specify where this element will be

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    align-content: flex-start;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "topblue topred"
                         "bottomgray bottomgreen";
}

.red {
    grid-area: topred;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
}

.blue {
    grid-area: topblue;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.green {
    grid-area: bottomgreen;
    background: green;
    text-align: center;
}

.gray {
    grid-area: bottomgray;
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    .container {
        grid-template-areas: "topred"
                         "topblue"
                         "bottomgreen"
                         "bottomgray";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="red">
      Red <br /><br /> Column 2, Top
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
      Blue <br /><br /> Column 1, Top
    </div>
    <div class="green">
      Green <br /><br /> Column 2, Bottom
    </div>
    <div class="gray">
      Gray <br /><br /> Column 1, Bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, be aware of [browser support of css grid](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid)

Comment: On second thought my request seems to require more explanation. I have provided that in the code.

Comment: You can just modify the `grid-template-areas` to look the way you want, you can see on each sub element I provide a `grid-area` to specify where it will be position on the `grid-tempate-areas`

Comment: What if some columns have a dynamic height due to either long or short content? AFAIK using `grid` will make the cells at the same height.